# Issue with Java Parceler

Tags: java, android, parcelable, parceler

I am building an Android app which connects to a REST server and I get this error in class that models server's response:

Error:(16, 15) error: Parceler: Unable to find read/write generator for type java.lang.Object for com.myapp.ServerResponse.result

I think the error is because I use generic type E. ServerResponse.java is:

```
public class ServerResponse <E> {
    @SerializedName("status")
    private int status;

    @SerializedName("result")
    private E result;

    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

Is any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Parceler opts for speed in this case so it will not use the `Parcels.wrap`/`unwrap()` by default, but if you'd like to handle generics you can use a `@ParcelPropertyConveter` that uses the `Parcels.wrap()`/`unwrap()` methods:

```
@Parcel
public class ServerResponse <E> {

    @ParcelPropertyConverter(ParcelsWrapperConverter.class)
    private E result;
}

public class ParcelsWrapperConverter extends NullableParcelConverter<Object> {

    @Override
    public void nullSafeToParcel(Object input, android.os.Parcel parcel) {
        parcel.writeParcelable(Parcels.wrap(input), 0);
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeFromParcel(android.os.Parcel parcel) {
        return Parcels.unwrap(parcel.readParcelable(ParcelsWrapperConverter.class.getClassLoader()));
    }
}
```

Just be sure the values you use in the ServerResponse are annotated with `@Parcel` or else Parcels will throw a runtime exception.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that you can't Parcel generics. (You can't Serialize unbounded generics either!)

When you have an instance of a generic class, that instance has its type erased at runtime so that there are only concrete types. At runtime, all instances of a generic type parameter are replaced by its bounds. Unbounded parameters like you use here are replaced by Object.

You might be able to do:

```
@Parcel
public class ServerResponse<E extends Parcelable> {
    @SerializedName("result")
    private E result;
}
```

This would replace E with Parcelable when the type is erased. The Parceler library claims to support any Parcelable types. You will need to make sure that the value in Result *is* parcelable, but you already need that to send it in a Parcel.

Comment: This error disappeared. Now I have this: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> org.parceler.transfuse.TransfuseAnalysisException: @Parcel code generation did not complete successfully.